# JsonProperty in JAVA - defining two variables using the same property

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am having a class like,

```
 public class Test {

    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<String> valuesString = null;

    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<Boolean> valuesBool = null;
}
```

if I give a list of string like below then it needs to be stored in valuesString,
body,

```
 {
   "values" : ["Test1", "Test2"]
 }
```

if list of boolean then valuesBool,

```
   {
       "values" : [false, true]
    }
```

As of now it is giving me 400 response.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixing my issue,

when we are passing boolean it's converted to String in  this case,

```
 public class Test {
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<String> valuesString = null;
}
```

request body,

```
    {
       "values" : [false, true]
    }
```

And if you want to get as a boolean in implementation use below,

```
Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```